# Would it make sense to use the unscented transform for linear problems too?

Tags: kalman-filter

I've just learned about the unscented Kalman filter and I have a theoretical question. Suppose our innovation and measurement processes are linear but we know the initial state covariance and/or the measurement noise is not gaussian. Nevertheless, suppose we happen to at least know the mean and covariance of these non-guassian distributions. Would it then be more sensible to use the unscented transform (instead of the vanilla KF equations) to better model transformations of these non-guassian distributions?

Comment: I can at least share my reasoning for the innovation step. In the "normal" UKF setup we think of the initial state being gaussian but the innovation step being non-linear. After one innovation, the new state is not gaussian, but we at least have an estimate for the mean and covariance. So if we instead consider we are initializing the UKF from this state, we are essentially starting with the non-gaussian initialization I mentioned in my main post.

Comment: this site is not a forum ... if you have anything to add to your post, then please edit your post

Comment: @jsotola I understand what you're saying, but I've been told literally the opposite by another maintainer in the SE ecosystem ("if you have context to add that doesn't need to be in the body of the question, use the comments").

Comment: the decision is up to you ... the question should stand on its own without any comments

Comment: @jsotola it does